# How to write my TCPDump data from a pipeline in Linux to a pcap file?

Tags: bash, named-pipes, pcap, plc, tcpdump

So I am writing a program on a PLC where I need to constantly record network traffic with TCPdump into a Linux Pipeline. Every x minutes I need to write the data from the pipeline into a pcap file while the pipeline is continuously reading data. I also need to filter the data and get only OPC UA and I need to get the IP-address and the message ( everything before the first 54 bytes I can throw away from the packet). The display filters don't need to be integrated into the script, since I can just manually get the pcap file into wireshark and apply opcua.servicenodeid.numeric in {673} || opcua.servicenodeid.numeric in {676} filters into that.

This is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_dir="/opt/plcnext/"  # Specify the output directory
output_base_name="capture"              # Specify the base name for the output files
interval=300                            # Specify the capture interval in seconds (5 minutes)

# Read data from the named pipe and save it to a pcap file
read_data() {
    current_time=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    output_file="${output_dir}/${output_base_name}_${current_time}.pcap"

    # Read data from the named pipe and save it to a pcap file
    cat mypipe > "$output_file"

    echo "Captured data saved to $output_file"

    # Clear the named pipe
    > mypipe
}

# Continuous loop to read data and save it every 5 minutes
while true; do
    read_data

    # Wait for the specified interval before capturing again
    sleep $interval
    echo "done sleeping"
done
```

Now my issue is that when I  write the data into a pcap file it doesn't get an entire TCPdump file. When that happens I cannot open the pcap file in Wireshark.

This is te code I currently have. The only thing this code does is read the data from my named pipe and save it into a pcap file.

Now the PLC doesn't have an package manager, so I'm pretty stuck with only a simple script without extra libraries.

If anyone has any experience with this and could help out then this would be amazing.
If you need more information, ask away.

Kind regards
Bren

Comment: There is a race condition: Data appended to `mypipe` between writing it to the output file, and clearing `mypipe`, is lost.

Comment: Named pipes (FIFOs) in Unix don't work asynchronously. They require rendezvous. When you open a pipe for writing, this blocks until another process opens it for reading or *vice versa*.  A new pipe object is then allocated for the two. This can be repeated: the next reader and writer can rendezvous using the same FIFO, and get their own pipe and so on.

Comment: The reason why I use a named pipe is to save memory on my PLC. When reading the data continuously I can just save the data into a pcap file, when that happens the data from the named pipe is not needed anymore and gets deleted. @user1934428